# SMBUS on STM32F091

Tags: stm32, smbus

Any example code available to implement smbus(master and slave) interrupt mode on stm32f091rc ? Tried using the HAL functions was not successful?

In Master mode to transmit I use

```
while(1)
{
  while(HAL_SMBUS_Master_Transmit_IT(hsmbus,sladd ,command_code,THREE_BYTE,SMBUS_LAST_FRAME_NO_PEC)!= HAL_OK);
  HAL_SMBUS_Master_Transmit_IT(hsmbus, sladd, command_code , THREE_BYTE,SMBUS_LAST_FRAME_NO_PEC);
}
```

sladd is slave address.
command code is 3 byte array.

In Slave Mode to receive on 2nd MCU(same as master controller )
Also I am calling   HAL_SMBUS_EnableListen_IT(&hsmbus1); to set the state in listening mode,because the Interrupt would only be enabled if smbus state was in listening mode, again this is not very clear in HAL user manual.
while(1)
{
while(HAL_SMBUS_Slave_Receive_IT(&hsmbus1, receive_buffer, 3, SMBUS_FIRST_AND_LAST_FRAME_NO_PEC )!= HAL_OK);
HAL_SMBUS_Slave_Receive_IT(&hsmbus1, receive_buffer, 3, SMBUS_FIRST_AND_LAST_FRAME_NO_PEC );
}
Actually I am not sure about where to call transmit and receive function(in while(1) or outside) since it is interrupt based we shouldn't be calling function in while(1) let me know if I am right or wrong?
Also wanted to know the procedure to receive and transmit messages in Smbus on stm32f091rc?(using HAL libraries)

Comment: Welcome to electronics.stackexchange.com. Would you mind formatting your question such that the code is displayed in a better readable format?

Comment: Check out my question. Maybe you can implement it for STM32F0. [STM32G0 Stuck on SMBUS Slave](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/634776/stm32g0-stuck-on-smbus-slave)